# Background-image load on mobile device only

Tags: html, css, media-queries, background-image, responsive

I'm trying to find a solution concerning a div. I want that the text to be at the middle of the background-image. In my code the the text and the background are purposely showing only a small screen. I tried text-align center and vertical-align: middle but it doesn't reach the expected result. Could someone have an idea of how to manage the code ?

```css
#yourimage {
  background-image: none;
}

#yourimage p{
  display:none;
}
    
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  #yourimage {
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/350x150/f22/fff');
    background-size:cover;
    background-image: block;
  }
  
  #yourimage p{
  display:block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
}
```

```html
<DIV id="yourimage">
<p>
Resize your browser window to see the image
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Because you are using `@media`

Comment: @MrLister you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the div also a fixed width & height. This Code should do the trick. And a good way to align items in the center is to use CSS Flex.

And furthermore, there is no `background-image: block;` CSS Property.

```css
#yourimage {
  display:none;
}
    
@media (min-width: 100px) {
  #yourimage {
      width:350px;
      height:150px;
      display:-webkit-box;
      display:-ms-flexbox;
      display:flex;
      -webkit-box-align:center;
      -ms-flex-align:center;
      align-items:center;
      -webkit-box-pack:center;
      -ms-flex-pack:center;
      justify-content:center;
      background: url('http://placehold.it/350x150/f22/fff');
      background-size:cover;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="yourimage">
  <p>
    Resize your browser window to see the image
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: n the case I want my picture to be full screen do I have to put a fixed width & height?

Answer (score 0):

You must use webkit too. For browser compatibility. 
Please find below solution.

```css
#yourimage {
  display:none;
}
    
@media (min-width: 100px) {
  #yourimage {
      width:350px;
      height:150px;
      display:flex;
   display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
      align-items:center;
   -webkit-align-items: center; /* Safari 7.0+ */
      justify-content:center;
   -webkit-justify-content:center;
      background: url('http://placehold.it/350x150/f22/fff');
      background-size:cover;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="yourimage">
  <p>
    Resize your browser window to see the image
  </p>
</div>
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {margin: 0}

#yourimage > p {
  display: none;
}
    
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  #yourimage {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* centers flex-items (children) horizontally */
    align-items: center; /* and vertically */
    background: url('http://placehold.it/350x150/f22/fff') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 350px;
    max-width: 100%; /* responsiveness */
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto; /* horizontally centered on the page */
  }
  #yourimage > p {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="yourimage">
  <p>Resize your browser window to see the image</p>
</div>
```